# How to use LINQ select in one column with condition

Tags: c#, linq, select

Data Table like this ...

```
Date       Count
20160101   100
20160102   103
20160103   108
20160104   102
20160105   104
20160106   106
20160107   108
```

I want `select if => someday.Count > someday[-3].Count`

Result = 3Rows below:

> 20160104 ,because 102>100
>   20160105 ,because 104>103
>   20160107 ,because 108>102

Please tell me how to use LINQ?
Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you clarify your question, or use different wording? It's very difficult to understand what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is by doing it like this.

```
int index = 0;
var a = from i in someday
        let indexNow = index++
        where indexNow >= 3
        let j = someday[indexNow - 3]
        where i.Count > j.Count
        select i;
```

You create temporary variables j to get the element three steps before then compare it with the current element to check if it satisfies certain condition. If it is, then you select it

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Where`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb534803(v=vs.100).aspx) overload which takes `Func<TSource, int, bool> predicate` as input. The second input of this delegate is index of the current element. So, it means your lambda expression must take two inputs, which the first one will be the type of the your elements and other will be `Int32`.
`Where` method will automatically calculate the index of the current element.

```
var result = myColl.Where((x, index) => index >= 3 && x.Count > myColl.ElementAt(index - 3).Count);
```

Then you can use your desired method as `Select()`, `ToList()` and etc.

***P.S:*** I have assumed that the name of the object is `myColl`.

***Additionally:***

I always like to tell developers about `http://referencesource.microsoft.com/`. You can easily find implementation of all methods and everything about the source code of C#.
Here is the source code of this overload of `Where` method if you interested.

```
    public static IEnumerable<TSource> Where<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, int, bool> predicate) {
        if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
        if (predicate == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("predicate");
        return WhereIterator<TSource>(source, predicate);
    }
```

As you see it will return `WhereIterator` and it will calculate index of the current item automatically and send it to your method:

```
static IEnumerable<TSource> WhereIterator<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, int, bool> predicate) {
    int index = -1;
    foreach (TSource element in source) {
        checked { index++; }
        if (predicate(element, index)) yield return element;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the indexed `Where`-overload as follows:

```
var result = myDates.Where((x, index) => index >= 3 && x > myDates.ElementAt(x - 3).Count);
```

This selects all those elements from your collection which have a greater count thatn this one from the elements from three days before.

Answer (score 1):

While the indexed techniques described in other answers will work, they will be inefficient if the source sequence is not list based, in which case `ElementAt` will cause a O(N^2) time complexity operation.

A possible better way with just O(N) time complexity (if the source sequence does not itself include a heavy operations) is to use a combination of [Skip](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985(v=vs.100).aspx) and [Zip](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd267698(v=vs.100).aspx), like this

```
var result = myDates
    .Skip(3)
    .Zip(myDates, (current, compare) => current.Count > compare.Count ? current : null)
    .Where(item => item != null);
```